# Special chars not displayed correctly

Tags: linux, debian, localization, utf-8

I have problem when I copy file from Server A (Debian 7.4) to Server B (Debian 7.4). Polish special characters in files are not displayed correctly on Server B (in mcedit).

I created file with polish special character on server A. It is displayed correctly on Server A. When I run `locale` on Server A i got `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8` Other variables except `LANGUAGE` and `LC=ALL` also are set to `pl_PL.UTF-8`. Then I tar file, and on Server B I download the tarred file with wget command. On Server B I untar file and when I look at the file content (mcedit) then polish letters are displayed incorrect. There are "diamonds" instead of special chars. When I run `locale` on server B then `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Other variables except `LANGUAGE` and `LC=ALL` also are set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Then I run database migrations (php script) and corrupted data is inserted into database. When I add rows in migration then polish special chars are replaced by strings like `Å›` (polish letter `ś` is replaced by `Å›`).

I checked in mcedit that file on server A and on server B has the same value on both servers. Polsih letter 'ś' is C5 9B (hex) on both machines.

The worst thing is that every time there are special chars I have to manually check and correct errors in database.

Probably when I edit column values in database by php migration script it also corrupts my data in database. Once I read data from table, then manipulated and then saved and my data was also corrupted.

If I change locales on Server B to `pl_PL.UTF-8` then special chars in other languages (like german, czech etc.) will be working OK? If it it is problem with fonts then why also database migrations are corrupted? I am using UTF-8 then every special char from every language should be displayed correctly? How to properly display special chars from every language and what to do to php migrations were performed correctly?

UPDATE 1:
Server A `locale -a` outputs:

```
C
C.UTF-8
pl_PL.utf8
POSIX
```

Server B `locale -a` outputs:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

On both servers locale -m outputs a lot of charmaps (seems the same on both machines)

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `locale -a` and `locale -m` to make sure Server B has the correct locales and charsets installed to properly interpret pl_PL.UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for response.I updated my question to with output of both commands. Do I have to install locale (pl, de, fr ...) for every language that I want to display/use correctly?

Comment: Yes, I would expect at minimum, both servers will need the pl_PL.utf8 locale to properly display the special characters in that set. Based on the server settings you've shown, this seems consistent with the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I've already run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` then added pl_PL.utf8 and set default locale to pl_PL.utf8. Now polish letters are stiil displayed wrong. When I used `mc` it was localized to polish, but special letters were displayed incorrectly.